# Release memory after loading the Bitmap

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

In my app I put two Bitmaps. When the orientation is vertical, show the first image, if it's horizontal, show the second image. Using

```
Log.i("log","Total memory " + title + " = " + (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1024));
```

I found that **after I change my phone's orientation a few times, the total memory grows**. However, I would expect the memory to remain the same, it seems like the program is not properly freeing memory.

**Here's my code**

```
public  Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(int path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight, Context ctx){
    // Читаем с inJustDecodeBounds=true для определения размеров
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), path, options);

    // Вычисляем inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Читаем с использованием inSampleSize коэффициента
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), path, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Реальные размеры изображения
    Log.i("log", "inSampleSize" + reqWidth);
    Log.i("log", "inSampleSize" + reqHeight);
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    Log.i("log", "height" + height);
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    Log.i("log", "height" + width);
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Вычисляем наибольший inSampleSize, который будет кратным двум
        // и оставит полученные размеры больше, чем требуемые
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
            Log.i("log", "inSampleSize" + inSampleSize);
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

private void readImage(int draw) {

    //int px = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(draw);
    int pxW = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int pxH = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    ***if(bitmap != null){
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;
    }***

    bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(draw, My_px_W, My_px_H, this);
    ivStart.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

**Here's onCreate**

```
 if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        My_px_W = 200;
        My_px_H = 150;

        readImage(R.drawable.im2);



        logMemory("'vertical'");
    }
    else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        My_px_W = 400;
        My_px_H = 200;

        readImage(R.drawable.s2);
        logMemory("'horizontal'");

    }
```

Comment: @TravisHeeter How did you get Russian code into your edit?

Comment: Just make sure you aren't doing this too often- garbage collection is expensive!  At the very least, if you're doing this with multiple bitmaps every time the device changes orientation, make sure you're only running 1 collection.

Comment: When I stay in horizontal (set first image) I have first count of memory (27160), when I stay in vertical (set second image) my memory grow(31032), then I stay in horizontal again(set first image) and my memory more grow(39432).

Comment: Floegipoky I'm running three collection, second and third collection have many bitmaps, but I write about one collection to understanding principle to release memory.

Comment: kenorb in my apps comments I write on Russian language.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `System.gc()`after you called `recycle` if you want it to be immediately released.

Recycle on it's own is not enough as the garbage collector is not called.

> Free the native object associated with this bitmap, and clear the
>   reference to the pixel data. This will not free the pixel data
>   synchronously; it simply allows it to be garbage collected if there
>   are no other references. The bitmap is marked as "dead", meaning it
>   will throw an exception if getPixels() or setPixels() is called, and
>   will draw nothing. This operation cannot be reversed, so it should
>   only be called if you are sure there are no further uses for the
>   bitmap. This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called,
>   since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no
>   more references to this bitmap.

Comment: Thank for your answer Bojan, but System.gc() doesn't release a memory of my image. When I stay in horizontal (set first image) I have first count of memory (27160), when I stay in vertical (set second image) my memory grow(31032), then I stay in horizontal again(set first image) and my memory more grow(39432).

Comment: Then my friend, you have a memory leak!

Comment: not really. System.gc() is just a hint. it doesn't guarantee to call anything. and it should never be necessary in production code. read the docs on this before suggesting it as an answer please

Comment: But that hint works most of the time. Calling it twice increases your odds to almost 100%...

Answer (score 0):

You should call `bitmap.recycle()` and then call `System.gc()`

Be sure you aren't using the same bitmap after call recycle()

Comment: When I stay in horizontal (set first image) I have first count of memory (27160), when I stay in vertical (set second image) my memory grow(31032), then I stay in horizontal again(set first image) and my memory more grow(39432).